# Quiz question on keigo

Tags: word-choice, nuances, keigo, anime

While stumbling across [Lucky Star episode 15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifMy4LvZINk&t=601s) (26-second clip, from **8:51 - 9:17**), I found that there was a scene where the characters were watching a quiz show, where one of the questions asked was on keigo:

> Ｑ：「**行く**」の謙{けん}譲{じょう}語{ご}はなんでしょうか。
>
> Ａ：正{せい}解{かい}は「**参{まい}る**」でした！
>
> (The characters were all certain it was **伺{うかが}う**, but they all agree with **参る** later.)

Now, if I am not mistaken, 伺う is used when the act of going to a place involves the listener (eg. saying はい、うかがいます！ to one's boss, when asked to go to him) and 参る is used when the movement is **not** related to the listener (eg. not the boss' company, country, home, etc.). I think both verbs are humble forms of 行く.

---

**Why, then, is 参る preferred as an answer to 伺う?** Is there a nuance I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there were many blog entries on keigo usage that said both 参る and 伺う are 謙譲語 for 行く, all of the dictionaries I checked (広辞苑, 新明解, 大辞林, etc.) agreed that 伺う is a 謙譲語 for **訪問する／訪れる**, not 行く.

So the quiz segment is technically correct, even though it seems like a lot of people think 伺う is also a 謙譲語 for 行く. This is probably because 参る and 伺う are often interchangeable.

In terms of nuance in usage, I think the more important distinction is:

- 参る humbles yourself in relation to the **listener**
- 伺う humbles yourself in relation to the **place** you're visiting (or **someone** who is there)

So you can say 「妹のいる東京に参ります」 but not 「妹のいる東京に伺います」.

---

You can read more on the [two types of 謙譲語](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E8%AC%99%E8%AD%B2%E8%AA%9E%E2%85%A0%20%E8%AC%99%E8%AD%B2%E8%AA%9E%E2%85%A1), categorized by who the humbleness is directed toward.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 伺う means more "to visit" than "to go". Thus, 伺う is more like the humble form of 訪{たず}ねる.

Of course, "visiting" someone/somewhere does necessarily involve changing locations, but because (訪ねる / 伺う) can both be *transitive*, the emphasis seems to be on who/what you are visiting (the direct object).

With regard to 行く and 参る, both are only *intransitive*. The subject is the "actor" and he/she is simply going somewhere. The emphasis seems primarily to be the act of "going". Perhaps because 参る and 行く are strictly intransitive, is feels like a better fit. And grammatically, it is definitely a better fit.